# Fixing SharePoint 2013 Foundation performance issues

Tags: performance

Can any one can give the permanent solution for slow performance of Sharepoint 2013 foundation server?  My server has 32 GB RAM. If I enter the data to list, I got the server unable to save this time error. I am always restarting the search host controller service to solve this problem.

Please any one can tell me the permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set configuration to guarantee performance. It all varies on how SharePoint is being used. I recommend you read through the [Capacity Planning articles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758645(v=office.15).aspx) and [test results and recommendations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608068(v=office.15).aspx) so you can get a set up that works well for you.

If you have trouble going through all the literature, I'm sure you can find a Partner in your area to help you out. It's not that you won't find help here, it's just that it all depends on so many different things.

Comment: when server RAM eating full by services, i restart the search host controller service. Instead of restarting search host controller is there any permanent solution is there?

Comment: you could try having your site indexed only at night, when users wont be affected by it